# How to dynamically convert html table rows to columns?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

To modify the database format SQL uses two functions called `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`. I was wondering, is there a way of achieving the same thing using a script on the client side?

Let's take this table for example:

```
Rowa. pro_img#1|${product.name}|${product.price}|${product.description}
Rowb. prod_img#2|${product.name}|${product.price}|${product.description}
Rowc. prod_img#3|${product.name}|${product.price}|${product.description}
Rowd. pro_img#4|${product.name}|${product.price}|${product.description}
```

As you already know, every html table with dynamic data will print `rows`. What i'm trying to do is having an html table with dynamic data printing `columns` so I can display a nice product listing like in this example:

```
Product_img#1|             Product_img#2|            Product_img#3|
Product_name|              Product_name|             Product_name|
Product_price|             Product_price|            Product_price|
Product_description|       Product_description|      Product_description|
```

I'm trying to display 3 objects per row. Is there a way of doing this with a simple javascript?

I'm trying to achieve exactly the same thing as [Vans (example here)!](http://www.vans.com/shop/mens-shoes)

### Edited New code

```html
<div id="product_container">
                <c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter">
                
                    <div id="product_image"><a href="viewProduct?${product.id}">
                                    <img class="img" alt="" src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.id} (1).jpg" /></a></div>
                    <div id="product_name">${product.name}</div>
                    <div id="product_price">${product.price}</div>
                    <div id="add_toList"><form id="wishlistForm" action="addToWishlist" method="post">
              <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">

              <input class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToWishlist'/>" type="submit">
            </form></div>
            
                    <div id="add_toCart"><form id="cartForm" action="addToCart" method="post">
              <br>
              <br>

              <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">
              <input class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>" type="submit">


            </form></div>
                    
                    
                    
                    
            </c:forEach>
                </div>
```

Comment: I think it's unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by "html table with dynamic data"? What javascript and/or server-side framework(s) are you using?

Comment: do you have 2 line of code for us?

Comment: you could make a table with 3 columns and put lists for the ocjects in the cell but I wouldn't use tables for this, bootstrap's container (or other libraries) make it really easy.

Comment: @cutmancometh: What I mean by "html table with dynamic data" the data/content is retrieved from the database so it's not a static table where the content is written on the client-side.

Comment: @maraca: Very Interesting. I never thought of that... Can you explain in more depth for a beginner? I kinda understand what you mean but not fully tho... `:/` Thanks man.

Comment: The structure of an HTML table won't change because the data is dynamic, it's still essentially just `<tr>`'s and `<td>`'s with your code deciding which data goes into which `<td>`'s.

Comment: @drs9222: Exactly... But how to change that?

Comment: @user45678 I'd have to see the code that creates the html to say.

Comment: I understand, but how are you getting the data from the database, to the html?

Comment: @drs9222: I'm trying to do the exact same thing here: http://www.vans.com/shop/mens-shoes

Comment: @cutmancometh: I'm getting the data from the database to the html with `ControllerServlet`. Everything is set in the `Servlet`. I'm basically building using MVC technique.

Comment: You're getting an html table (e.g. 3x5) and want to swap its colums and rows (so it becomes 5x3)?

Comment: As I understand it he has normal rows in a database and wants to display each row vertically (colums on top of each other)  and one next to each other (3 per content row) and then start with the next content row. Well I don't know if this helped

Comment: @Samurai: Yes this is kinda the idea... I just added some more code.

Comment: @maraca: Yes exact! Just as shown when you shop at vans.com.

Comment: @user45678 ok, then what I've shown you is one possible solution... amongst infinite ones ;-)

Comment: @maraca: Your solution appears to be the one they used. By inspecting their site they indeed created divs for each object. I'm trying it live. And come back to make your answer official if it works.

Comment: So, you could do it *without* having to create divs. You could change the way the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements are laid out using CSS. I'll build you the CSS to do it, but I need a look at the HTML. Or at least an idea of how the table gets generated.

Comment: @cutmancometh: I have pasted more code! The full table is in this post. The way I generate the table is with these jsp tags: `<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter"></c:forEach>` Then using markups like: `${product.name}` to retrieve the data.

Comment: ah I don't think you have to do it as I did, you can just create divs directly in the forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create custom divs for each object:

```
function generateProductDiv(product) {
   return
     '<div class="product">' +
         '<img src="' + product.image + '">' +
         '...' +
     '</div>';
}
```

Create a div for each product put them in a parent divs and style them with css (the CSS property `display: table;` and `table-*` might be of interest to you if you want to do it this way, another possibility is to use libraries).

The easier solution is just to put those divs inside the cells of a table although you should only use tables if you really want to display tabular data.

You seem to have JSP code, not Javascript, here is how to generate the `form`s in JSP (btw. JSP is the same as Java Servlets, just another way of writing it, simply put: JSP = html with Java, Servlet = Java with html). Using forms instead of divs because that seems to be what you want:

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter">
    <form id="wishlistForm" action="addToWishlist" method="post">
        ...
        <a href="viewProduct?${product.id}">
            <img class="img" alt="" src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.id} (1).jpg" />
        </a>
        ...
    </form>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Hey maraca! As a programmer who doesnt have lots of experience, i'm a bit struggling with trying to achieve your solution... So far I have created the divs and placed the functions ${product.name} etc in the respective divs... At this point, all there is left to do is javascript to create new divs... I have to admit that i'm a bit lost and confused... Would you like to help me further more? That would be very much appreciated... I can provide you with the new code I did. `:)`

Comment: @user45678 Why do you want to create new divs? I don't see any ajax calls, so it is static or not (from client view)? You are using JSP it seems, not javascript? You should get just a "list" of divs (now probably all on top of each other and the image etc. inside not styled yet, but that's not such a big problem). If you have the divs and try to arrange them and just don't succeed, you can post another question, best with jfiddle or something similar, then it's easiest to help

Comment: First, I thought I had to create new divs. Second, it is dynamic from the client side...  Third, yes I'm using JSP. I asked for a javascript solution because I thought that's what I needed.To be honest,  I have a hard time understanding how to do what I want to do. I don't know where to start `:S` I know how to style the divs with css. I just don't know how to create the divs dynamically so that each product display on the page. Have you seen the Vans example in my post? This is what im trying to do.

Comment: @user45678 I added the code, now you will get a bunch of forms, the foreach you just put inside a div or another container so that all forms are inside and then you arrange and style the forms with CSS

Comment: @user45678 it doesn't really matter, you can use divs and put the forms inside (you want to use forms right?) or only use forms, both element can be styled the same way

Comment: Can we continue in chat? It will be easier to understand each other :)

Answer (score 3):

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/v4fow8an/1/)

This function takes an HTML table and returns a table which has the given table's rows and columns swapped.

Example input:

```
----------------
A1  |  A2  |  A3
----------------
B1  |  B2  |  B3
----------------
```

Output:

```
---------
A1  |  B1
---------
A2  |  B2
---------
A3  |  B3
---------
```

**Javascript:**

```
function convertTable(tbl) {
    var rows = tbl.rows.length;
    var cols = tbl.rows[0].cells.length;
    var tbl2 = document.createElement('table');

    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            var tdih = tbl.rows[j].cells[i].innerHTML;
            td.innerHTML = tdih;
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        tbl2.appendChild(tr);
    }
    return tbl2;
}
```

Comment: Nice fiddle, actually it answers the question in the title better, but applied to his problem, when he wants to style the products it will be easier with the divs.

Comment: Thanks. And agree, I wouldn't use table for showing a list of products,  but asked the OP in the comments and it seemed swapping rows and columns is what s/he wanted.

Comment: I used the word convert because my first language isn't english so excuse me if I didn't use the right word! Yes <<converting>> is what he wants to display rows as columns. I used a table to display a list of products because that's how I learned to do it. I didn't know there were other better methods. I'm learning a lot right now. I'm self teaching myself how to code so I don't have a teacher or resources like that to help me out.

Comment: @user45678 no worries, English is not first language for most of us. But we're still communicating quite well and we're all learning new things every day and finding better ways to solve our problems. :)

Comment: @Samurai: Yes! Exact! I love it! So you're saying the best way to display a list of products would be using custom divs as suggested by maraca?

Comment: Yes, using divs is surely the most common way of doing it.

Comment: @user45678 only calling you "he" because ure name is a bit complicated ;-) Also no native English speaker. If you have not much experience with CSS then I wouldn't try to arrange the divs yourself, better use a library (one example: bootstrap) or go for the simple approach with putting the divs in a normal table, if all product divs have the same size it will look good.

Comment: @maraca: Haha yeah I didnt find any cool name for this site yet lol. Working on it. As for my level of comprehension, I'm an experimented web designer (html and css) but not programmer. All other languages are strangers to me. But so far I have a good understanding of jsp and a bit of java. I'm looking forward to learn more about java and c++ but that's not the subject. Thanks for  your help I will mark you as official answer!

Comment: @Samurai: I will give you 1+ for your post. I wish I could mark two answers as official because you did a very good job dude!

Comment: Sure, just glad to help :)

Comment: @user45678 glad it helped too (btw the downvotes are probably because of the formatting of the html... although sometimes you will just get downvoted for no reason) and thanks for accepting

Answer (score 0):

The best (easiest, most maintainable, most semantic) way to do this is *pure* CSS. You shouldn't have to change the markup at all.

And it's actually pretty easy.

You just have to get the browser to stop treating it like table data. The key is the `display:` CSS property.

`display` defaults to `table-row` for `<tr>` elements and `table-cell` for `<td>` elements, which makes sense. You have to "break" that property.

```
tr, td {
    display: block;
}
```

In other words, you're telling the browser to  "display table row and table data elements just like any other block-level element (like a div, for example)".

This gets you almost all the way there. Now you have to get the table "rows" (which are now being laid out like `div`s) to stack next to each other, instead of on top of each other.

```
tr {
    float: left;
}
```

Now, you end up with the possibility of the new "rows" not being the same height. If, for example, your product images are not all the same height, or if your descriptions are different lengths, you'd end up with the table being way out of alignment.

So, you need to give your `<td>`s all the same height.

```
td{
    height: 150px; /*or whatever height you want*/
}
```

So, the full CSS code looks like this:

```
tr {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
td {
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Obviously, this is only the most basic code to get your foot in the door. In the real world, you'd give each type of `<td>` its own height, something like:

```
td.product-image {
    height: 150px;
}
td.product-description {
    height: 70px;
}
td.product-price {
    height: 40px;
}
```

Here's a codepen that puts it all together: [table data pivoted](http://codepen.io/CutmanCometh/pen/JddwWm)

Also, [here's some more info on the CSS `display` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) if you're interested.

Best of luck. Feel free to ask in comments if you have any further questions.

Comment: The guys above seem to agree that the best way of displaying a product list is with divs and javascript. Apparently there are many ways to achieve what i'm trying to do. I'm still a bit struggling with javascript but right now i'm trying to create what maraca suggested to do. If you have any other ways of doing it... Maybe easier ways for a total beginner... Your suggestions would be very welcomed :)